# Change hyperlink colour with BEM

Tags: css, bem

I am trying BEM for the first time today.

Why is my link colour not different from the default?

It really should be yellow, right?

```css
.nav-primary {

  &__menu {
    color:red;
    }
    
  &__menuitem {
      color:green;
    }
    
  &__menuitem a {
      color:yellow;
    }      

  }
```

```html
<div class="nav-primary">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">why am I not a different colour?</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you referring to BEM as in the methodology?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're targeting different elements ie.

```
.nav-primary {

  &__menu {
    color:red;
    }

  &__menuitem {
      color:green;
    }

  &__menuitem a {
      color:yellow;
    }      
  }
```

will compile to:

```
.nav-primary__menu { color: red; }   
.nav-primary__menuitem { color: green; }
.nav-primary__menuitem a { color:yellow; }
```

which doesn't correspond to any elements in your html.

I guess you need to add `nav-primary__menuitem` class to your "element", which in your case would be a list item, as so:

```
<div class="nav-primary">
    <ul>
        <li class="nav-primary__menuitem"><a href="">why am I not a different colour?</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Only then your last rule will apply to your link.

But to BEM-ify your code, you need to decide what is the Block, and what is an Element of this block in your html structure. So in your code you'd likely want to also add a class to your link element. Providing that you want your block to be a `nav-primary` element, use ie `.nav-primary__menulink` class on a link too:

  why am I not a different colour?

then your CSS/SASS/LESS will look:

```
.nav-primary {

      &__menu {
        color:red;
        }

      &__menuitem {
          color:green;
        }

      &__menulink {
          color:yellow;
        }      
      }
```

Comment: Many thanks, @robjez - this makes sense to me now. Would you say that's the best way to do things in my case?

Comment: BEM is only very useful class naming convention, which helps to write more maintainable css, and if you think you need this type of convention in your project, use it. Remember to modularize your markup for that purpose - figure out what's block, what is element and adhere to class naming convention - and you will surely find out, how useful it is, especially from the selector point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Following the BEM documentation I would do the following:

```
.nav-primary {

  &__menu {
    color:red;
  }

  &__menuitem {
    color:green;
  }

  &__menuitem a {
    color:yellow;
  }      

}
```

And then alter your html to:

```
<div class="nav-primary">
    <ul>
        <li class="nav-primary__menuitem"><a href="">why am I not a different colour?</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could think more modular here, so you have a wrapper `nav-primary` and a module `list` which is highly reusable. And you should not target the `a` by Tagname because it slows down your css extreamly.

```
<div class="nav-primary">
    <ul class="list  list--plain  list--nav-primary">
        <li class="list__item  [list__item--nav-item or nav-primary__item]">
            <a class="[list__item-link or nav-primary__item-link]" href="">why am I not a different colour?</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And modifing the list items should then be done via modifyer like `list__item--nav-important` for the red colored one, for example.